# Using a selector "$(this).find()" jQuery inside a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery and this is my code for the click event of any labels.

```
$('.spin span:last-child').click(function(){
  unitPrice = parseFloat($(this).closest('.product').find('.unit-price span').text().substring(3));
  if ( $(this).parent().find($('.custom-input')).val() == "" ) {
    $(this).parent().find($('.custom-input')).val(1);
    inputValue = parseInt($(this).parent().find($('.custom-input')).val());
    subTotal = parseFloat(inputValue * unitPrice).toFixed(2);
    $(this).closest('.product').find('.total-price span').text(subTotal);
  } else if ( inputValue =! "" ) {
    inputValue = parseInt($(this).parent().find($('.custom-input')).val());
    inputValue += 1
    $(this).parent().find($('.custom-input')).val(inputValue);
    subTotal = parseFloat(inputValue * unitPrice).toFixed(2);
    $(this).closest('.product').find('.total-price span').text(subTotal);
  };
});
```

so , i created a function to optimize the code:

```
      function getValues(){
        unitPrice = parseFloat($(this).closest('.product').find('.unit-price span').text().substring(3));
        subTotal = parseFloat(inputValue * unitPrice).toFixed(2);
        return subTotal;
        $(this).closest('.product').find('.total-price span').text(subTotal);
      };
```

and my new block code should be look like this:

```
$('.spin span:last-child').click(function(){
  if ( $(this).parent().find($('.custom-input')).val() == "" ) {
    $(this).parent().find($('.custom-input')).val(1);
    inputValue = parseInt($(this).parent().find($('.custom-input')).val());
    getValues();
  } else if ( inputValue =! "" ) {
    inputValue = parseInt($(this).parent().find($('.custom-input')).val());
    inputValue += 1
    $(this).parent().find($('.custom-input')).val(inputValue);
    getValues();
  };
});
```

but my function "getValues" don't work , the selector "$(this).find..." inside a function should be the problem i think, can you guys help to fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than worrying about making `this` inside `getValues`, I would suggest altering the function definition to allow which element you're working with to be passed to it.

You also have some errors in your function: `return`ing will end execution if that function, so the line after `return` will currently not run, and you should always use `var` to declare variables. You're not using the result of this function, so you really don't need the `return` statement at all.

```
function getValues(spanEl) {
    var unitPrice = parseFloat($(spanEl).closest('.product').find('.unit-price span').text().substring(3));
    var subTotal = parseFloat(inputValue * unitPrice).toFixed(2);
    $(spanEl).closest('.product').find('.total-price span').text(subTotal);
  };
```

and then anywhere you call `getValues()`, change it to `getValues(this);`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass `this` as an argument to the function:

```
getValues(this);
```

and define the function like:

```
function getValues(element){
    unitPrice = parseFloat($(element).closest('.product').find('.unit-price span').text().substring(3));
    subTotal = parseFloat(inputValue * unitPrice).toFixed(2);
    return subTotal;
    $(element).closest('.product').find('.total-price span').text(subTotal);
};
```

See [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing `this` variable inside `getValues` function. but `this` is not available in function. you should pass this object explicitly.
You can do like blow:

```
function getValues(obj){
    unitPrice = parseFloat($(obj).closest('.product').find('.unit-price span').text().substring(3));
    subTotal = parseFloat(inputValue * unitPrice).toFixed(2);
    return subTotal;
    $(obj).closest('.product').find('.total-price span').text(subTotal);
  };
```